# POST - Slim PHP

Tags: php, web-service, slim

Sou iniciante em webservices e estou estudando em cima do Slim (PHP) mas estou tendo um pequeno problema na hora de salvar algo no banco de dados. A minha função para tentar salvar uma nova categoria no banco é a seguinte:

```
function addCategoria(){
    global $app;
    $req = $app->request();
    $paramName = $req->params('name');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO category ('nameCategory') VALUES ($paramName);";
        try {
            $db = getDB();
            $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
            $stmt->bindParam("nameCategory",$paramName);
            $categorias = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;
            echo '{"categorias": ' . json_encode($categorias) . '}';
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }       
}
```

Já testei e sei que o nome da categoria está chegando no ws mas quando executo um teste recebo isso:

[
  42000
]

E nada é salvo no banco. Até o momento já consegui utilizar os outros métodos mas infelizmente estou tendo trabalho com o PUT.
Caso alguém possa ajudar agradeço.

Comment: `42000` seria o sql state(código do erro normalmente) retornado? qual banco está usando? vc faz um insert e depois faz uma pesquisa( `fetchAll()`) pq?

Comment: O erro retornado está sendo esse:
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'testes' in 'field list'}}
Utilizando o MySql. E com relação ao fetchAll acabei utilizando por estar no tutorial que tentei utilizar, como eu havia dito sou realmente inciante quando o assunto é ws.

Comment: Esse código de erro não tem nada a ver com o código da pergunta, que estranho. vc está constuindo um ws e esse método está com problema? ou vc está consumindo?

Comment: O erro mudou depois que eu alterei o tipo de aspas. Antes estava 'nameCategory' e eu alterei para `nameCategory`. E a resposta abaixo resolveu a questão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query está incorreta.
A estrutura correta seria:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO category (nameCategory) VALUES ('$paramName');";
```

Comment: Era realmente isso (Um erro bem idiota da minha parte).
Agradeço a ajuda de todos.